# Explicit construction of an outer isomorphism in a $p$-group.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, p-groups

Recently, I stumbled upon a theorem by Wolfgang Gaschütz (see below) that every non-trivial $p$-group which is non-trivial has an outer automorphism. However, the proof uses cohomology theory and as far as I can see, the proof is non-constructive.

I have also found a refinement of this theorem by Schmid, another elementary proof by Webb and the proof in Huppert's book (all non-constructive to my eye).

Does anybody know whether there exists a sort of algorithm or at least a constructive proof of an outer automorphism?

*Schmid, Peter*, [**Normal (p)-subgroups in the group of outer automorphisms of a finite (p)-group.**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01214085), Math. Z. 147, 271-277 (1976). [ZBL0307.20016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0307.20016).

*Gaschütz, W.*, [**Kohomologische Trivialitäten und äußere Automorphismen von p- Gruppen**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01112225), Math. Z. 88, 432-433 (1965). [ZBL0199.06302](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0199.06302).`

Comment: Perhaps this is better on MathOverflow . . .

Comment: I think, but I am not 100% sure right now, that the Webb proof is constructive, in that you go up a chain of subgroups, each maximal in the last, starting with an abelian subgroup of maximal order, which obviously satisfies the result. I'm just reading my version of her proof from my $p$-groups notes and it looks that way.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, isn't there a problem in the proof of Lemma 2 in Webb's paper? She says that "if $\alpha$ is a non-inner automorphism of $G$ which centralizes $G/N$ and $N$ then...". There is no explicit mentioning of how to obtain $\alpha$ in this case, is it?

Comment: To my understanding, the proof is a contradiction, where she says "if we have a non-inner automorphism, we have nothing to prove, otherwise it leads to a contradiction".

Comment: @Aericura You might well be right. I was just skimming through it. There is a point where it doesn't look constructive. My version isn't constructive, I don't think, but I haven't thought about it for a while.